# Issues with pattern matching and case expression over Data.Typeable.TypeRep

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am trying to pattern match on Data.Typeable.TypeRep in the following code:

```
import Data.Typeable (TypeRep, typeOf)

tyI = typeOf (1    :: Int)
tyD = typeOf (3.14 :: Double)
tyB = typeOf (True :: Bool)

func1 :: TypeRep -> Bool
func1 tyI = False
func1 tyD = False
func1 _ = True

func2 :: TypeRep -> Bool
func2 tr = case tr of
    tyI -> False
    tyD -> False
    _   -> True

func3 :: TypeRep -> Bool
func3 tr = if tr == tyI then False else
           if tr == tyD then False else
           True
```

... and I get these warnings on compilation:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /home/[..]/test.hs, interpreted )

/home/[..]/test.hs:8:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In an equation for ‘func1’:
        func1 tyD = ...
        func1 _ = ...

/home/[..]/test.hs:23:12: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In a case alternative:
        tyD -> ...
        _ -> ...
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

Also, I get the surprising results:

```
*Main> func1 tyI
False
*Main> func1 tyD
False
*Main> func1 tyB
False -- !!!

*Main> func2 tyI
False
*Main> func2 tyD
False
*Main> func2 tyB
False -- !!!

*Main> func3 tyI
False
*Main> func3 tyD
False
*Main> func3 tyB
True -- Ok!
```

So only the last function func3 seems to produce the expected results. What should I do to use the pattern matching (func1) and case (func2) functions to work properly over TypeReps?

Comment: Enable more warnings with `-Wall`: in this case the shadowing of the global binding with the local one should also be reported, providing further insight on your issue.

Comment: `TypeRep` is supposed to get a big shake-up in GHC 8.2. If that happens, you'll probably find it far more useful than now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `tyI` and `tyD` are being considered as ordinary variables (as opposed to being compared to the global constants of the same name) in the pattern match. The code below is completely equivalent to yours.

```
func1 :: TypeRep -> Bool
func1 x = False
func1 y = False
func1 _ = True

func2 :: TypeRep -> Bool
func2 tr = case tr of
    x -> False
    y -> False
    _ -> True
```

As you've observed in `func3`, the way to solve this is to make the comparison explicit. You could also do it with guards:

```
func4 :: TypeRep -> Bool
func4 tr | tr == tyI = False
         | tr == tyD = False
         | otherwise = True
```

---

In general, the only things permitted on the left hand side of the equals against which you can pattern match are constructors. The one exception is number literals, and you'll notice that using these in patterns incurs an `Eq` constraint on the function as a whole

```
even :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> Bool
even 0 = True
even 1 = False
even n = even (n-2)
```

Similar exceptions to this rule are added if you add `OverloadedLists` and `OverloadedStrings`. The rule still holds for almost all cases.

Comment: Thanks. By any chance would you happen to know if there is a way to refer to "the global constant of the same name" in the code for TypeReps? Is there any TypeRep litterals? Eg "Typeable.Int", "Typeable.Bool"? I can't see any in the docs (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html). I think that'd allow me to keep the pattern matching function. Otherwise I'll stick with func4 style.

Comment: Nope, no hope for that avenue - `TypeRep` is purposefully opaque (no constructors exported). Really `func4` is your best bet for this. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `tyI` here:

```
func1 :: TypeRep -> Bool
func1 tyI = False
```

has nothing to do with the `tyI` defined here:

```
tyI = typeOf (1    :: Int)
```

In fact, your definition of `func1` could have been written:

```
func1 :: TypeRep -> Bool
func1 x = False
```

And the same holds for `func2` - the variables `tyI`, `tyB` and `tyD` there are just pattern variable names and do not refer to your global bindings.

However, your use of `tyI` and `tyD` in `func3` do refer to the global definitions, so that's why `func3 tyB` returns True.